# win32gui SendMessage not working correctly in libreoffice

Tags: python, winapi, libreoffice, win32gui, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to print a message in LibreOffice Writer with python, using the function

`win32gui.SendMessage(window_id, win32con.WM_CHAR, ord('a'), 0)`

The expected result in notepad:

[image: Notepad]

The result in Libreoffice Writer

[image: Libreoffice Writer]

The character "a" was printed 65536 times.

I have also tried using the PostMessage function instead of the SendMessage, as well as the below way of printing

```
win32gui.PostMessage(window_id, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, ord('a'), 0)
time.sleep(0.1)
win32gui.PostMessage(window_id, win32con.WM_KEYUP, ord('a'), 0)
```

The results were the same.

Comment: Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).